# Exclude certain pattern?

Tags: regex

I have the follow pattern

```
Administrator        yes
User                 yes
Userb                yes
userc                yes
userd                yes
```

I want a match when there is any user followed by yes (with an arbitrary number of spaces in between them) that is NOT Admin,User,and Userb

I've attempted negative lookaheads and negative lookbehind. For example for the case of Administrator, I've tried this

```
(?<!Administrator)\s+yes
```

However, there is still a match for the line with Administrator, I suspect because of the \s+.  Much help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what about case sensitivity? `userb yes` should be matched or not? please split the examples in 2 categories (match / do not match)

Comment: What programming language are you using? Are you sure you need regex here? Can you not just split the line on whitespaces and check what the username field contains?

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct. `\s+` will just match a single space (for example!) and then this space would not be preceded by `Administrator` but by another space. This is not easily solved, because including the `\s+` into the negative lookbehind is only allowed in .NET (other regex engines cannot handle variable-length lookbehinds).

However, if you use multiline mode (how to activate it depends on your language/tool), then you can use a negative lookahead instead:

```
^(?!Administrator|User|Userb)\w+\s+yes
```

In multiline mode `^` will match at the start of every line.

**Update:** In fact, after writing this, I did come up with a solution using a lookbehind. Simply make sure, that you execute the lookbehind right after a bunch of word-characters:

```
\w+(?<!Administrator|User|Userb)\s+yes
```

Now `\s+` has to match all of the spaces, otherwise they would not be preceded by word characters.

Note that both solutions are problematic with non-prefix free users. The first one will not match the user `Userbob` while the second one will not match `ThatUser`. This could be solved using word boundaries:

```
^(?!(?:Administrator|User|Userb)\b)\w+\s+yes
\w+(?<!\b(?:Administrator|User|Userb))\s+yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
^(?!Administrator|User).*yes
```

http://www.rubular.com/r/ijyZT0Eaas